# Remmina can't remote into Windows Server

Tags: ubuntu, remmina

I'm trying to use Remmina on Ubuntu to remote into one of the servers at my work. However, after entering the connection information in I get the following error:

"You requested an H264 GFX mode for ser X@X.com, but your libfreedp does not support H264. Please check colour depth settings."

I am quite new to Ubuntu in general so I am not really sure what to do about the above error.

Could anybody help me out?

Cheers

Comment: See Bart Koppers's answer. I found the other answers, without instructions on how to get to "Remote Desktop Preference," pretty useless.

Answer (score 52):

quoting from the following GitLab issue link:

> in the profile Basic settings, change the colour depth untill you find the one that is supported by your server.

[image: from that link]

[remmina issue explained](https://gitlab.com/Remmina/Remmina/issues/1584)

if you have some issues to find the profile basic settings, check the [remmina user's guide](https://gitlab.com/Remmina/Remmina/-/wikis/Usage/Remmina-User%27s-guide)

Comment: Thank you very much. It is very useful and work fine. Thanks again

Comment: I'm sorry if I'm mistaken, but my Remmina Remote Desktop Client does not have a Color Depth option :/

Comment: what protocol have you chosen? we were referring from the start to RDP.

Comment: @TheSHETTY-Paradise, instead of simply writing the host-name and pressing 'Enter', you need to press the `+` sign to create a new profile - then you will see these options and can also save them as default

Comment: Can you explain how to get to the above "Remote Desktop Preference" GUI? The Remmina Gitlab link also doesn't give instructions for that, so I had to follow @Bart Kopper's suggestion below to launch from terminal with `remmina -n`

Comment: i have added to the answer the remmina user's guide, it's useful and complete with pictures.

Answer (score 7):

In my case **GFX RFX (32bpp)** fixed the issue

[image]

Comment: It works for me!

Comment: likewise, it's certainly very usable!

Answer (score 5):

Ubuntu 18.04 LTS [comes with `libfreerdp` that doesn't support](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/freerdp2/+bug/1769348) the "H264" mode the Remmina client uses by default.

In addition to the workaround noted in the other answers (changing the Color Depth to one not requiring H264), you can install the most recent version from the [official PPA](https://github.com/FreeRDP/Remmina/wiki#for-ubuntu-users-we-have-an-official-ppa-with-remmina-12):

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:remmina-ppa-team/remmina-next
sudo apt update
sudo apt install remmina remmina-plugin-rdp remmina-plugin-secret
sudo killall remmina
```

Comment: While the answer is the best here as for me, I would not recommend to use potentially "unsecure" commands from the answer. I would simply recommend to use only commands from official pages that has much lower risk to be compromised and can be treated "safer". It is better to go to https://remmina.org/ first, find an official link to project on GitLab at the bottom of the page, navigate to Wiki page within GitLab project.

Answer (score 2):

Tried all step, but I did not get this to work on Pop OS connecting to Win10/Win Server. 
Seems, that if no profile is available, only Quick Connect is available, and there are no options visible to change a profile.
Solution: start remmina from terminal (commandline) with -n option to create profile:

1. Open terminal
2. `cd ~/.local/share/remmina/`
3. `remmina -n`
4. Enter server, credentials, resolution
5. Choose a compatible protocol and color depth like GFX RFX (32bpp) or True Color (32bpp)
6. Try to Connect and/or Save

Comment: +1. The other answers, without a way to get to "Remote Desktop Preferences," is pretty useless. Common failing among these "answers" that assume you already know half the answer.